# JMenuBar does not enable after being disabled

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I'm disabling a `JMenuBar` before displaying a `FileDialog` (as the menu items are still active when the `FileDialog` is visible) using `getJMenuBar().setEnabled(false)` and then calling `getJMenuBar().setEnabled(true)` after the `FileDialog` closes, but the menu items do not become active after being enabled - they will if I change to another application and back to mine. I've tried calling         `getJMenuBar().revalidate()` and/or `getJMenuBar().repaint()` to no avail.

Of note, I'm using a screen menu bar as I'm on OS X. Sample code that shows the problem:

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MenuTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuItem menuItemNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    private JMenuItem menuItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    private JMenuItem menuItemSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    private JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    public MenuTest() {
        super("JMenu Test");
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        menuItemOpen.addActionListener(this);

        menuFile.add(menuItemNew);
        menuFile.add(menuItemOpen);
        menuFile.add(menuItemSave);
        menuBar.add(menuFile);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void openFile() {
        getJMenuBar().setEnabled(false);
        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);
        getJMenuBar().setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == menuItemOpen) {
            openFile();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguements) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        new MenuTest();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for comments / suggestions!

Comment: Why?  Isn't `FileDialog` a modal dialog?

Comment: It is.. it disables the windows behind it, but not the menu bar. It would disable the menu bar too if I didn't set the system property to have it as a screen menu bar for OS X.

Comment: Ahh, you might want to point out that you're on OSX in your question ;)

Comment: Thanks, have updated :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I could resolve the issue by enabling/disabling each `JMenuItem` and not the menu bar or menu itself.

I also did everything on the EDT, just in case that was the problem, but it didn't help.

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MenuTest implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuItem menuItemNew = new JMenuItem("New");
    private JMenuItem menuItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");
    private JMenuItem menuItemSave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    private JMenu menuFile = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JFrame frame;
    public MenuTest() {

    }

    public void buildGui(){
        frame = new JFrame("JMenu Test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        menuItemOpen.addActionListener(this);

        menuFile.add(menuItemNew);
        menuFile.add(menuItemOpen);
        menuFile.add(menuItemSave);

        menuBar.add(menuFile);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void openFile() {
        menuItemNew.setEnabled(false);
        menuItemOpen.setEnabled(false);
        menuItemSave.setEnabled(false);

        FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a file", FileDialog.LOAD);
        fd.setVisible(true);

        menuItemNew.setEnabled(true);
        menuItemOpen.setEnabled(true);
        menuItemSave.setEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            openFile();
        }

    public static void main(String[] arguements) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
            new MenuTest().buildGui();
                });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm Matt's answer worked for me on macOS. But there are some things he didn't mention that I will, in the hope that it saves someone some time.

### Thing 1

I tried disabling only the `JMenu` components in the `JMenuBar` so that I would have to write only one `for` loop. I got the same behavior that I got when I tried to temporarily disable the `JMenuBar`.

```
        JMenuBar b = getJMenuBar();
        for (int i=0; i<b.getMenuCount(); i++)
            b.getMenu(i).setEnabled(false); // then true later
```

### Thing 2

By only temporarily disabling the `JMenuBar`, if I do one of the following, the menu items would work again:

1. focus on another app and then focus on this app
2. make this app interact on the Event Dispatch Thread in any way

### Thing 3

You do not want to blindly disable and later enable a `JMenuItem` afterward if it was already disabled beforehand.

```
private ArrayList<JMenuItem> disabledMenuItems = new ArrayList<JMenuItem>();

private void disableAppMenuItems () {
    JMenuBar b = getJMenuBar();
    for (int i=0; i<b.getMenuCount(); i++) {
        JMenu m = b.getMenu(i);
        for (int j=0; j<m.getItemCount(); j++) {
            JMenuItem mi = m.getItem(j);
            if (mi != null && mi.isEnabled()) {
                mi.setEnabled(false);
                disabledMenuItems.add(mi);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void undoDisableAppMenuItems () {
    for (JMenuItem i : disabledMenuItems)
        i.setEnabled(true);
    disabledMenuItems.clear();
}
```

### Thing 4

Not every `JMenuItem` in a `JMenu` can be disabled or enabled (e.g., `JSeparator` components). That's why the above code covers the case where a `JMenuItem` is null.