# Can't re-enable OSX menubar

Tags: java, macos, swing, menu, look-and-feel

I have a program that uses multiple different `JMenuBar`s for different windows (via `JFrame.setJMenuBar()`). We've discovered that in OSX, in certain situations, one of these menu bars can become disabled, and it appears to be impossible to re-enable it after the fact. Here's my simple example:

```
public class Demo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
      try {
         UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error setting LAF: " + e);
      }
      new MyFrame("Alpha frame");
      new MyFrame("Beta frame");
   }

   public static class MyFrame extends JFrame {
      public MyFrame(String title) {
         super(title);
         final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
         JButton button = new JButton("Toggle menu") {
            @Override 
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
               return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
         };
         add(button);
         button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               menuBar.setEnabled(!menuBar.isEnabled());
            }
         }); 

         JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
         fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Dummy action"));
         menuBar.add(fileMenu);
         setJMenuBar(menuBar);
         pack();
         setVisible(true);
      } 
   }    
}
```

If you disable one of the frame's menubars using its button, then switch focus to the other frame, switch back, and click the button again, the menubar does not become re-enabled visually -- menu items remain grayed out and inoperable, but the `isEnabled()` method will return true.

This is an issue because certain modal dialogs appear to automatically disable the current menubar. I've seen it happen with `JFileChooser`, and I've also seen it happen with `FileDialog`. There may be some issues with exceptions in the event dispatch thread as well; I haven't done a detailed analysis. Ideally I would just make certain that whenever a given window gains focus, its menubar is automatically re-enabled -- but the `setEnabled()` method of `JMenuBar` doesn't actually do anything if you've switched focus to a different window, as my demo demonstrates.

How do I fix this?

(Java 6, much to my chagrin, we'll update to Java 8 as soon as physically possible)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Somehow missed this similar issue in my earlier searches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085966/jmenubar-does-not-enable-after-being-disabled . Switching application focus does properly re-enable the menu. That's not a proper fix though.

Comment: ...and switching application focus only works sometimes; most of the time the menu stays disabled anyway.

Comment: Ha. Doing `setMenuBar(null)` followed by `setJMenuBar(getJMenuBar())` fixes everything _except_ for the Help menu, which remains broken. If I rename our Help menu to "Help2" then it re-enables properly -- clearly "Help" is a special string of some kind in the OSX look and feel and it's being handled improperly. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to coerce the help menu into doing what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have to disabled the `JMenuItem`s and not the `JMenuBar`. The code to disable the menu bar:

```
for(int i = 0; i<menuBar.getMenuCount(); i++){
    JMenu menu = menuBar.getMenu(i);
    if(menu==null) continue;
    for(int j = 0; j<menu.getItemCount(); j++){
       JMenuItem item = menu.getItem(j);
       if(item==null) continue;
       item.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

The code to enable the menu bar.

```
for(int i = 0; i<menuBar.getMenuCount(); i++){
    JMenu menu = menuBar.getMenu(i);
    if(menu==null) continue;
    for(int j = 0; j<menu.getItemCount(); j++){
       JMenuItem item = menu.getItem(j);
       if(item==null) continue;
       item.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```