# How can I properly call NSOpenPanel from a JNI method to run on the proper thread?

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, java-native-interface

I can get my JNI class to only partially execute due to my unfamiliarity with Objective-C and JNF. What I've tried so far is as follows:

Here's Open.java, which an MCV for a more significant Java Swing app that deserves a better-looking better-featured open file dialog than unreasonable `java.awt.FileDialog` or the ugly and less-featured `javax.swing.JFileChooser`.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Open extends JFrame {
   public Open () {
      getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            try {
               NativeOpenFileDialog.run();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
               System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
         }
      }));
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() { new Open(); }
      });
   }
}
```

Here's NativeOpenFileDialog.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class NativeOpenFileDialog {
   static {
       System.loadLibrary("natopndlg");
   };
   public static native void run ();
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() { NativeOpenFileDialog.run(); }
      });

   }
}
```

Here's NativeOpenFileDialog.m

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#include <jni.h>
#include "NativeOpenFileDialog.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeOpenFileDialog_run (JNIEnv *thisEnv, jclass jcls) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
    [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    if ([panel runModal] != NSModalResponseOK)
        NSLog(@"User did not press OK");
    [pool release];
}
```

And here's the makefile (I'm using Xcode 15.2):

```
SDK = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk

Open.class: Open.java NativeOpenFileDialog.java NativeOpenFileDialog.m
    javac -h . NativeOpenFileDialog.java
    javac Open.java
    gcc -dynamiclib -o libnatopndlg.dylib -framework Cocoa -isysroot $(SDK) -I $(JAVA_HOME)/include -I $(JAVA_HOME)/include/darwin -fobjc-exceptions -std=c99 NativeOpenFileDialog.m
```

And here's how I execute it after executing `make`.

```
java Open
```

Clicking the button raises the exception:

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow should only be instantiated on the main thread!
```

Which is understandable knowing that the panel is supposed to be opened on the UI thread. I believe all I have to do is make sure the window created by NSOpenPanel is a child of the JFrame and opened on the UI thread. And I believe that at leasat means I would have to execute a Java function to get the NSWindow of the JFrame.

Comment: Please remove the ranting and clarify which of the problems mentioned is the focus of the question.

Comment: It's interesting how making the question more focused makes for a possible XY problem. That's because I cannot yet prove that FileDialog cannot do what I want. If it can, then I don't need to create a JNI method.

Comment: Then why not make the question about that?

Comment: After reading the openjdk source, it's a good bet that I can't use FileDialog. Besides, anyone who can read java can probably guess from my class name what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried making it work without Java?

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier version of the question, the application is a java swing application and the core java code has an insufficient call to NSOpenPanel. Context is often lost when there's too much focus. So, taking java out of the equation forever is not possible.

Comment: I don't mean removing yet from the question. I'm asking if you are able to create the native dialog without Java, to verify that the native code is correct.

Comment: Not entirely. What I did get running seems to violate some principles of Cocoa applications. But the open panel does appear to have all the features except the ability to select all items in the view. There is some evidence that NSOpenPanel has no select all items feature on its own, which is counter to everything I understand about good factoring.

Comment: In order to run just the NSOpenPanel in my experience you would have to place it inside of  int main(){NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication]; .... [application run]; return 0;}  I tried it with your code inserted in the main.m and NSOpenPanel ran as expected.

Comment: The problem is that there's no communication being added to this method that gets the parent window and java ui thread. Everything I've read is so old that it's no longer compilable. It might be an indication that nobody cares about the quality of the file open dialog experience.

Comment: Which file open dialog are you trying to use: AWT, Swing, or JavaFX?  What does NSOpenPanel do that the others don't?

Comment: `NSOpenPanel` is the basis of `java.awt.FileDialog`. it's the one with the most potential for a good user experience. The original version of my question made a good case for using it but at least one person didn't appreciate how strongly I made my case. So, now we have this lengthy comment conversation that would not be necessary if people took the time to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute things on the UI thread using dispatch_async() and dispatch_sync().  NSObject also includes a method `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` that will perform a selector on the main thread.

This is a gist using the Java objective-c bridge that does something similar to this:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3966989

For your specific problem you could wrap the method body in dispatch_async

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_NativeOpenFileDialog_run (JNIEnv *thisEnv, jclass jcls) {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
  [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
  [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
  if ([panel runModal] != NSModalResponseOK)
      NSLog(@"User did not press OK");
  [pool release];
});
```

}

Of course, this just opens the dialog and doesn't do anything with the file that the user selects, so you'll need to build on this.

Comment: Thanks. I had already written what I want when the user presses OK or Cancel. That part is easy but apparently not everthing is.

Comment: I needed to make it easier to return a list to the java caller, so I ended up using `dispatch_async_and_wait_f`, which I would not have found had you not led me in the proper direction.

Comment: Something interesting. When I used `dispatch_async_and_wait_f`, the java app hangs practically the entire system if I click anywhere in the apple menu bar after the NSOpenPanel is raised. I can escape by force quitting the app. I think there's a work around where I can use `dispatch_async` but it requires a significant amount of coordination between the jni call and the class it's called from.

Comment: As soon as I add code to call the calling class' setFiles method, the hang happens.

Comment: There are some hazards to be conscious of related to threading.  Eg if you're calling your function from the EDT then you're blocking the edt which you never want to do.  Easy solution is to spawn a thread and call your jni function from there.  Make sure that if you have callbacks that you return to the EDT (eg invokeLater) before doing swing stuff.

Comment: If you need it to be modal (ie blocks user input) then you can use a the foxtrot library to block the execution of your method without actually blocking the edt.  https://github.com/sbordet/foxtrot

Comment: I was able to get the solution working by using the `SwingWorker` class but in doing so, the app's JMenuBar was left in an enabled state. I was able to work around it in sloppy fashion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77962852/1707353. There might be something better than I can do in the jni code.

Comment: And now that I'm using `SwingWorker`, I can use `dispatch_async_and_wait_f`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more complete answer resulting from the comments on Steve's answer, which will remain accepted.

Here is `Open.java`, which takes on the `SwingWorker` that was not effective in `NativeOpenFileDialog.java`.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Open extends JFrame {
   public Open () {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
         public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void,Void>() {
                String[] files = null;
                public Void doInBackground () throws Exception {
                   files = NativeOpenFileDialog.run();
                   return null;
                }
                protected void done () {
                   // May want to undo disabled app menu items here
                   if (files != null) {
                      for (String s : files) {
                         System.out.println("s is " + s);
                      }
                   }
                }
            };
            // May want to disable enabled app menu items here.
            worker.execute();
         }
      }));
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() { new Open(); }
      });
   }
}
```

Here is a simpler `NativeOpenFileDialog.java` that excludes the useless `SwingWorker`:

```
public class NativeOpenFileDialog {
   static {
       System.loadLibrary("natopndlg");
   };
   public static native String[] run ();
}
```

And here is `NativeOpenFileDialog.m`, which includes code to convey the accepted `String` values to the caller.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

#include <jni.h>
#include "NativeOpenFileDialog.h"

JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_NativeOpenFileDialog_run (JNIEnv *env, jclass jcls) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        __block jobjectArray arr;
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            jclass strcls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
            NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
            [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
            [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
            [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
            if ([panel runModal] != NSModalResponseOK) {
                NSLog(@"NSOpenPanel Cancel button pressed");
                arr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 0, strcls, NULL);
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"NSOpenPanel Open button pressed");
            NSArray *urls = [panel URLs];
            int count = urls == NULL ? 0 : [urls count];
            arr = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, count, strcls, NULL);
            if (urls != NULL) {
                int i = 0;
                for (NSURL* url in urls) {
                    NSString *path = [url path];
                    jstring str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, [path UTF8String]);
                    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, arr, i++, str);
                }
            }
        });
       return arr;
    }
}
```

The makefile remains unchanged in the MCV example.

The only thing I dislike about this solution is the fact that the application menu remains enabled while the `NSOpenPanel` is raised. I can [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77962852/1707353) it but I wish I didn't have to.